# Nuget package manager console Not found error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Premium. Out of nowhere the NuGet package manager console stopped working. Now it only displays `Not found` after the powershell initialization fails.

[image]

I tried reinstalling NuGet, restarting, removing the folder with NuGet extension.

Anybody has some idea what could be causing this or at least how to find out why is this happening?

Update:
Found this in ActivityLog.xml

```
Not found
 at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
 at System.Management.Automation.PipelineNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
 at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
```

Comment: please tell us version of nuget you are using

Comment: 2.8.60318.734, but I think it's not related to specific nuget version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue just randomly resolved itself. No idea why or how.